# flex hslider tooltip similar to Youtube seek position

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I don't see any similar tutorial enable you to get the time position when the mouse cursor is on that hslider position, how do I make it possible like Youtube's feature? With this trick, my application would be perfect! Using Flex 4, I hope the code is not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

keep a label over the hslider..make it invisible in the design view...when u do roll over call a function which sets the visibility of the label to true..on roll out make it invisible... this might help u i guess...

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get you and please write proper English.